# Beginning to code with java (No coding experience)

Tags: java, language-agnostic, user-experience

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Java book you have read so far](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91629/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far)

I want to learn java but, I have absolutely no coding experience.

what is the best website, book, or anything that is best at teaching java?

Comment: With no coding experience, you are ripe to have a positive Haskell learning experience. Is learning Java in particular required by some neccesity, or did you decide that learning Java equates to learning programming? If the latter, consider Haskell. If the former, my heart goes out to you. :)

Comment: If, on the other hand, you'd like to learn a language that you have a decent chance of actually using professionally: http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: And to combine the suggestions of the two above me: Learn a little from various languages. The more styles you're exposed to, the better you can program. It's fine if you're a "Java programmer" or a "Haskell programmer" but don't be just that.

Comment: Stanford has a class online... http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111

Answer (score 1):

[Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are your best resource. Start with "Trails Covering the Basics" and move on to the other tutorials as you see fit.

And of course the [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for reference:

Answer (score -1):

Download JAVA, and get into it, that is the best way to learn anything.

When I began learning Java I started here, there are some nice tutorials that go over all the basics on the bottom of the page.

[JavaRanch - Java Hello World, + Tutorials](http://www.javaranch.com/java-college.jsp)

Instead of giving you code to copy they give you what the output should be and links to the techniques you should use.

Also to make sure you aren't making things to complicated some of them say this should be done in X amount of lines.

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly suggest that you check local community colleges and technical schools for classes.

You are not likely to learn how to program well without some formal education.  Yes, without a formal education you can learn to copy code from examples and modify it, but that's not nearly the same thing.

Comment: I disagree, there are so many online resources for learning Java that a structured classroom environment really won't do too much for you if you have the willpower to learn it on your own. Plus you will save yourself quite a bit of money.

Comment: Well, I disagree with your disagreement.  A few people are able to learn on their own, but it's a relatively small number (and getting smaller, percentage-wise, all the time).  Think of how many people here DON'T know how to program, even though they're creating complex monstrosities.